# Angular route with multiple parameters

Tags: angular, angular-router, angular9

I have a page that will be open by another application with parameterized URL.

Ex: `sitename.com/language/myapplication?param1=xxx&param2=xxx`

In my component .ts I have:

```
this.param1= this.route.snapshot.queryParamMap.get('param1');
this.param1= this.route.snapshot.queryParamMap.get('param2');

this.router.navigate(['/myapplication'],
  {
    queryParams: {
      param1: this.param1, param2: this.param1
    }
  });
```

I am using routing module as well:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/myapplication', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'myapplication', component: myComponent },
  { path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent }
];
```

When I open the URL directly with the parameters it works fine.

**Problem 1:**

I have multi language on it, i18n, so when I change language via dropdown, the parameters disappear and it redirects to `mysite.com/language/myapplication` but I need something like `sitename.com/fr/myapplication?param1=xxx&param2=xxx`

**Problem 2:**

I want to force "page not found" in every scenario except when I have the URL with the parameters

**Problem 3:**

How can I transform those parameters from optional to required?

Comment: You can use AuthGaurd and the check there if Your URL has a parameter or not. ?

Comment: I will have an integration with Azure AD, maybe I can do it using it, I am not sure

Comment: I don't know about azure AD, but using AuthGuard you can check that.

Comment: Hi @FabioCardoso. Did you find a solution for this problem? I need the same than you and I don't know how to do it

Answer (score 1):

Use route parameter instead of query string.

In the routing module:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/myapplication', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'myapplication/:param1/:param2', component: myComponent },
  { path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent }
];
```

And in my-component.ts

```
this.param1= this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('param1');
this.param2= this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('param2');
```

If you need transform those parameters to optional add these lines to the routing module:

```
{ path: 'myapplication/:param1/:param2', component: myComponent },
{ path: 'myapplication/:param1', component: myComponent },
{ path: 'myapplication', component: myComponent },
```

Comment: the url will be `sitename.com/myapplication?param1=xxx&param2=xxx?` because I tried this but I got the not found page

Comment: after debugging de snapshot object, queryParams have values but params is empty

Comment: The URL will be `sitename.com/myapplication/xxx/xxx`.

Comment: that is not the purpose. I need the name of the parameters. It is a requirement by the CI that will open the page.

Answer (score 0):

Problem 1: It's not the job of angular router. You need to reload the browser with the right url for the language, do not use router for that, something like: `location.assign(location.href.replace('/fr', '/en-US'))`;

Problem 2: A guard, but I prefer handling this directly in the component because you can use the same treatment for scenario without parameters, or parameter's value is not valid (e.g: user not found)

Problem 3: Same as problem 2. There is no such thing such as required parameter with angular router

Comment: I'm not using router for language... i18n works like that, I just have to register locale data in app.module add it to provider and it works like a charm. The problem is when I have parameters in the URL. If I don't have parameters I don't need to replace anything to get the language to work.

Comment: for problem 2, my routing module is working without guard if I don't use parameters... `path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent` does the job

Comment: You means you can change the language dynamically without reloading? You are not using AOT?

Comment: No, sorry, the page is reloading. For multi language I am using the basic implemention of i18n. https://angular.io/guide/i18n

Comment: How do you do the switching language with the dropdown? I don't see why you can't keep the parameters

Comment: href="/en-US/" and href="/fr/" , how can I handle it with parameters?

Comment: By using `href="/en-US/"`, you are telling that user is always redirected to the root path of the application, which is static. If you want to have dynamical path ==> you need to use javascript: either to update the `href` property, or to go directly to the correct url like I did. Try this solution: `href="/en-US/"` by `href="#" onclick="location.assign(location.href.replace('/fr/', '/en-US/'))"`. Binding to `href` property is also an option.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215464/discussion-between-fabio-cardoso-and-htn).