# Angular - Edit route variables by name

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router

in my Angular 12 project I have routes like these:

```
 /:par1/:par2/something/page
 /:par1/:par2/something2/page2
```

I need to set par1 and par2 programmatically.

Right now I use this code to achieve that:

```
const url = this.router.routerState.snapshot.url;
const splittedUrl = url.split('/');
splittedUrl[1] = getPar1();
splittedUrl[2] = getPar2();
this.router.navigate(splittedUrl);
```

but I find it a really ugly solution.

Is there a way to set par1 and par2 by their name like we do when we get them from the activated route?

Comment: Use route parameter instead of the url. Check this out https://stackoverflow.com/a/62244291/3944673

Comment: @MickMorely I need to set, not to get. I do not need old route parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved today the same problem.

This is my approach:

import ActivatedRoute into the constructor

```js
constructor(private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute)
```

use activatedRoute for getting the urlSegment and map an array with all segments (apply your change where needed)

This is an example applied at your problem

```js
const url: string[] = this.activatedRoute.snapshot['_urlSegment'].segments.map((urlSegment: UrlSegment, index: number) => {
      if (index === 0) return getPar1();
      else if (index === 1) return getPar2();
      else return urlSegment.path;
});
this.router.navigate(url);
```